# Is there a smarter way of doing this function in VBA?

Tags: vba

```
    Public Function Test(x As String) As String
    
    Dim Convert As Integer
    Dim Search01 As Integer
    Dim Search02 As Integer
    Dim Search03 As Integer
    Dim Search04 As Integer
    Dim Search05 As Integer
    Dim Search06 As Integer
    Dim Search07 As Integer
    Dim Search08 As Integer
    Dim Search09 As Integer
    Dim Search10 As Integer
    Dim Search11 As Integer
    Dim Search12 As Integer
    Dim Search13 As Integer
    Dim Search14 As Integer
    Dim Search15 As Integer
    Dim Search16 As Integer
    Dim Search17 As Integer
    Dim Search18 As Integer
    Dim Search19 As Integer
    Dim Search20 As Integer
    
    Search01 = InStr(1, x, "OBCI¥¯ENIE Podatek") 
    Search02 = InStr(1, x, "Op³ata miesiêczna za kartê od") 
    Search03 = InStr(1, x, "Op³ata za prowadzenie rachunku od")
    Search04 = InStr(1, x, "Op³ata za transakcje od") 'YES
    Search05 = InStr(1, x, "PROWIZJA ZA PRZEWALUTOW") 'YES
    Search06 = InStr(1, x, "UZNANIE Odsetki od salda dodatniego") 
    Search07 = InStr(1, x, "Za wyp³atê gotówki z bankomatu")
    Search08 = InStr(1, x, "V. SOL") 
    Search09 = InStr(1, x, "DOP. VISA")
    Search10 = InStr(1, x, "za wyp³atê z bankomatu") 
    Search11 = InStr(1, x, "Prowizja za przewalutow")
    Search12 = InStr(1, x, "Sprawdzenie dostêpnych") 
    Search13 = InStr(1, x, "Za wyp³atê z bankomatu kraj")
    Search14 = InStr(1, x, "Op³ata za wznowienie karty") 
    Search15 = InStr(1, x, "Op³ata za przelew BlueCash") 
    Search16 = InStr(1, x, "Op³ata miesiêczna za kartê") 
    Search17 = InStr(1, x, "WYP")
    Search18 = InStr(1, x, "Op³. za przelew ELIXIR")
    Search19 = InStr(1, x, "Op³. za przelew na rach. banku - BZWBK24")
    Search20 = InStr(1, x, "Pobrane odsetki od salda ujemn")
    
    If Search01 = 1 Then Convert = 1
    If Search02 = 1 Then Convert = 2
    If Search03 = 1 Then Convert = 3
    If Search04 = 1 Then Convert = 4
    If Search05 = 1 Then Convert = 5
    If Search06 = 1 Then Convert = 6
    If Search07 = 1 Then Convert = 7
    If Search08 = 1 Then Convert = 8
    If Search09 = 1 Then Convert = 8
    If Search10 = 1 Then Convert = 7
    If Search11 = 1 Then Convert = 5
    If Search12 = 1 Then Convert = 9
    If Search13 = 1 Then Convert = 7
    If Search14 = 1 Then Convert = 10
    If Search15 = 1 Then Convert = 11
    If Search16 = 1 Then Convert = 12
    If Search17 = 1 Then Convert = 13
    If Search18 = 1 Then Convert = 14
    If Search19 = 1 Then Convert = 14
    If Search20 = 1 Then Convert = 15
    
Select Case Convert
        Case 1
            Test = "Bank-Charge Tax collected."
        Case 2
            Test = "Bank-Monthly fee for Debit card."
        Case 3
            Test = "Bank-Monthly Account maintenance fee."
        Case 4
            Test = "Bank-Monthly Fee for transactions."
        Case 5
            Test = "Bank-Commission for currencies conversion."
        Case 6
            Test = "Bank-Interest on the credit balance."
        Case 7
            Test = "Bank-Charge for withdrawing cash from ATM."
        Case 8
            Test = "Transactions Debit Card"
        Case 9
            Test = "Bank-Account Balance request"
        Case 10
            Test = "Bank-Debit Card Replacement fee"
        Case 11
            Test = "Bank-BlueCash electronic Tranfer"
        Case 12
            Test = "Bank-Monthly Debit Card Fee"
        Case 13
            Test = "Bank-Lodgement"
        Case 14
            Test = "Bank-Transaction charge for bill payments."
        Case 15
            Test = "Bank-Interest charged on the negative balance."
                
        Case Else
            Test = "Transactions Debit or Credit"
End Select
End Function
```

Is there a smarter way of writing this function?

Comment: Indeed. Use _arrays_.

Comment: Is the input x the same as one of the Instr statements or a substring?

Comment: This would be best implemented/maintained as a lookup table on a worksheet (which could be hidden).  You can either use vlookup with wildcards or read the information into an array and loop over that.

Comment: @freeflow I think I miss led you the instr() function contains a subset of the x String. V. SOL 421352******3609 PŁATNOŚĆ KARTĄ 26.99 PLN MPL S 11 BALICE =  "V. Sol"

Comment: @freeflow, file it, and remember for the future, the VBA exercise, was a precursor to writing a function in SQL Server, I'm toying with using an SSIS transform to create an integer field in my SQL Server Table with a definition list of translations, I wrote a similar function using a dictionary in VBA, but the function was considerably slower than my original function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is predicated on the input String 'x' being one of the strings used in the Instr function.  A neat solution is to use a decoupled dictionary.  A decoupled dictionary uses two dictionaries.  The first maps an input to a code, the second uses the code to return a value.  The advantage of a decoupled dictionary is that you don't have duplicated items.  The code below is a bit ugly as it keeps the two dictionaries static within a method rather than placing them at module or global level.

```
Public Function Test(x As String) As String
    
    Static myInputSD As scripting.dictionary
    If myInputSD Is Nothing Then
    
        Set myInputSD = New scripting.dictionary
    
        With myInputSD
        
            .Add "OBCI¥¯ENIE Podatek", 1
            .Add "Op³ata miesiêczna za kartê od", 2
            .Add "Op³ata za prowadzenie rachunku od", 3
            .Add "Op³ata za transakcje od", 4
            .Add "PROWIZJA ZA PRZEWALUTOW", 5
            .Add "UZNANIE Odsetki od salda dodatniego", 6
            .Add "Za wyp³atê gotówki z bankomatu", 7
            .Add "V. SOL", 8
            .Add "DOP. VISA", 8
            .Add "za wyp³atê z bankomatu", 7
            .Add "Prowizja za przewalutow", 5
            .Add "Sprawdzenie dostêpnych", 9
            .Add "Za wyp³atê z bankomatu kraj", 7
            .Add "Op³ata za wznowienie karty", 10
            .Add "Op³ata za przelew BlueCash", 11
            .Add "Op³ata miesiêczna za kartê", 12
            .Add "WYP", 13
            .Add "Op³. za przelew ELIXIR", 14
            .Add "Op³. za przelew na rach. banku - BZWBK24", 14
            .Add "Pobrane odsetki od salda ujemn", 15
        
        End With
        
    End If
   
    
    Static myLookupSD As scripting.dictionary
    If myLookupSD Is Nothing Then
    
        Set myLookupSD = New scripting.dictionary
    
        With myLookupSD
        
            .Add 1, "Bank-Charge Tax collected."
            .Add 2, "Bank-Monthly fee for Debit card."
            .Add 3, "Bank-Monthly Account maintenance fee."
            .Add 4, "Bank-Monthly Fee for transactions."
            .Add 5, "Bank-Commission for currencies conversion."
            .Add 6, "Bank-Interest on the credit balance."
            .Add 7, "Bank-Charge for withdrawing cash from ATM."
            .Add 8, "Transactions Debit Card"
            .Add 9, "Bank-Account Balance request"
            .Add 10, "Bank-Debit Card Replacement fee"
            .Add 11, "Bank-BlueCash electronic Tranfer"
            .Add 12, "Bank-Monthly Debit Card Fee"
            .Add 13, "Bank-Lodgement"
            .Add 14, "Bank-Transaction charge for bill payments."
            .Add 15, "Bank-Interest charged on the negative balance."
            
        End With
        
     End If
     
     If myLookupSD.exists(myInputSD.Item(x)) Then
     
        Test = myLookupSD.Item(myInputSD.Item(x))
        
    Else
    
        Test = "Transactions Debit or Credit"
        
    End If
    
End Function
```

The scripting dictionaries used above require either a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Tools.References) or the replacement of 'New Scripting.Dictionary' with 'CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")'.

A final, a quite reasonable alternative, would be to replace the scripting dictionaries with collections or two dimensional arrays.  For collections you need to remember that the entry format is .add item,key and not .key,item.  For arrays you have to mess about with all those ugly indexes so serves you right if you go that way.

Comment: I don't know the etiquette on this site so I apologize in advance if I come across as a smart Alec or rude, but there are two errors in your code one a misspelling of a variable "myINpitSD" and two an  "end if " left out. having said the above I thank from the bottom of my heart for you taking the time to help me.